# How to format 2010-11-24 date in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using

```
((DateTime)newsItem.Date).ToString(@"yyyy MM dd")
```

which gives me 2010 11 24 but not 2010-11-24.

I want dashes in between the numbers of date.

Comment: Why the cast to DateTime? Is `Date` an `object`?

Comment: @ck No, `Date` is not a separate object. `Date` is a property of `DateTime` which returns a new `DateTime` with the time set to midnight. In this case the cast is not needed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried

```
((DateTime)newsItem.Date).ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Also, since you format the time part away anyway in the `ToString`, you don't need to add `.Date`, and you can change it to

```
((DateTime)newsItem).ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Yup, and you don't even need the "@" in the string either, although it doesn't do any harm: ((DateTime)newsItem).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: @Matt - That is correct. No characters to escape in that string, so in this case it's actually redundant.

Comment: And actually the format he wants is a Standard DateTime Format String: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131217/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111010-1.aspx
This will help you.